# trying to expose a class member to be public and readonly or a public constant

Tags: c#, struct, asp.net-4.0, scope

i am stuck with a simple variable assignment , the only condintion to make it littl complex for me
is that i need the struct values to be private , so they wont be modified alswhwere

and to be able to use values of the struct  but in a safe way, i am trying to use public `readonly` variables . so that's how i can share information with the application in read only mode , shouldn't it be simple ?

what am i missing ?

as the application starts in `Page_Load` i am calling `SetTablesMetaDetails()`

```C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      .... some other App inits here
    }
    
    else
    {
 
    }    

    // this method should be the one that instanciates the DbTable struct
   //..thus sets the values of tables "Name" and "ID"
   currProjData.setTablesReferences(); 
}
```

- The `struct`, will be used to assign values :

```C#
            public class DBMetaDetails
            {
                public struct DbTable
                {
                    public DbTable(string tableName, int tableId): this()
                    {
                        this.TableName = tableName;
                        this.TableID = tableId;
                    }

                    public string TableName { get;  set; }
                    public int TableID { get;  set; }
                }
            }
```

- The current project class to hold values

```C#
public static class currProjData 
{
    static DBMetaDetails.DbTable CustomersMeta = new DBMetaDetails.DbTable();
    static DBMetaDetails.DbTable TimesMeta = new DBMetaDetails.DbTable();

    public static void SetTablesMetaDetails()
    {

        TimesMeta.TableID = HTtIDs.TblTimes;
        TimesMeta.TableName = HTDB_Tables.TblTimes;

        CustomersMeta.TableID = HTtIDs.TblCustomers;
        CustomersMeta.TableName = HTDB_Tables.TblTimeCPAReport;

    }

    public static readonly int CustomersTid = CustomersMeta.TableID;
    public static readonly string CustomersTblName = CustomersMeta.TableName;

    public static readonly int TimesTid = TimesMeta.TableID;
    public static readonly string TimesTblName = TimesMeta.TableName;
}
```

My Problem is that i need those two sets of tables (`Tid` & `TblName`) details to be exposed to rest of application but as application starts it calls the `SetTablesMetaDetails()`

and the four last lines does not execute , i've tried moving this section into `SetTablesMetaDetails()`
but it's not the correct syntax , i am geting errors ,

**What is the correct way to acomplish assignment of `CustomersTid`?** <sub>(offcorse rest of the 3 as well)</sub>

public static readonly int CustomersTid = CustomersMeta.TableID;

this is what i am missing cause i don't know how to get it initialized in same way the struct above does ... preferebly in one method call

Comment: Side note: Mutable `struct` may make you cry. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil before allowing `set` on members of your `struct`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, trying to comprehend what exactly is mutable vs immutable , not realy understanding what's the difference , as building the struct was trial and error than adding `:this()` to it solved the problem for me, so if you could also supply an example to how you will code it propperly i will be glad!

Comment: `public string TableName { get;  private set; }`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov trying to access the  `TimeMeta.TableID` struct within the `SetTablesMetaDetails()`: Error- "set accessor is inaccessible" (tried it yesterday ..that's why i tried without private modifier, i was asking everyone here no reply)

Comment: `TimeMeta = new DBMetaDetails.DbTable("bla","bla")` does not work for you?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov,nop , as i commented last , `TimeMet.TableID =1` within the scope of `SetTablesMetaDetails()` red squggily line under TimeMeta.TableID saying :`The property or indexer.... cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible`, thats as soon as i add private modifier , Any idea ALexei ??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785551/initializing-properties-with-private-sets-in-net/2785576#2785576 have a look at this link for an answer as to proper usage with private

Comment: Just assign whole structure in `SetTablesMetaDetails`: `TimesMeta = new DBMetaDetails.DbTable(HTtIDs.TblTimes,...)` instead of `TimesMeta.TableID=HTtIDs.TblTimes;TimesMeta.TableName =...`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yea thanks i know i actualy . with your interruption (your first Comment) that helped me to come to a solution , i have searched for the answer because u insist that it should not give error , now **FOR ASSIGNMENT** no matter if you just put it somewhere like where you put all your globals , don't need a class dont need anything no method to initialize it (acutlly if i did put it in the `SetTablesMetaDetails()` scope it will not compile . though now there's no need for `SetTablesMetaDetails()` just put it with all globals , so now you can access it globally for reads only !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Properties

```
public static int CustomersTid { get { return CustomersMeta.TableID; } }
public static string CustomersTblName { get { return CustomersMeta.TableName; } }

public static int TimesTid  { get { return TimesMeta.TableID; } }
public static string TimesTblName  { get { return TimesMeta.TableName; } }
```

Comment: so now when i try to use /access `currProjData.CustomersTid` as a property, in some method around the application it will not be null or zero cause it is assigned(by  `CustomersMeta.TableID`) while it's being called ?

Comment: i was asking you in my last comment something about the usage , as i didn't wait for more than 30 minutes to your reply i tried replacing my fields with the properties in your example , so just by replacing those fields with ypur code(propeties ) made the values get to be inside the variables(properties) before i tried it with your solution they were empty/null so your answer does help ! i dont know why though others imply to set the setter with private modifier cause the way suggested other than yours leads to error , so thanks alot , marked as correct one

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify them locally, but read them globally, add a modifier to the setter:

```
public string TableName { get;  private set; }
public int TableID { get;  private set; }
```

Could also be `internal` or `protected` if you want to.

Comment: could you better explain or give a simple Example , as i find @Jmonsorno Answer to the right direction and your answer does apply to the struct but not addressing how to inintialize public `CustomersTid`(that is the public accessable value) with `CustomersMeta.TableID` struct private value

Comment: i did implement it with your version, a one that i did know about a day before this post, thought i did not know how to avoid the simple problem of the setter bing inaccsessible so i just threw it away (: had not time to deal with it , aventualy i did learn to use it so thanks for your help.